# ASP.NET: Problems using Timezone in Profile to convert from UTC

Tags: asp.net

Users have their timezones stored in ASP.NET profiles as strings.  I want to use those timezones to convert from UTC for a given user:

```
Dim timezoneFromProfile = HttpContext.Profile("TZ").ToString
Dim timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString(timeZoneFromProfile) ' FAIL
Dim convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timezone)
```

The problem is that TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString() expects its input to **not** be just a string such as:

> (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)

I can serialize the user's TimeZoneInfo into the ASP.NET Profile perhaps using XML, but I'm led to believe that using anything other than simple types such as Strings and Integers results in poor performance with respect to Profiles.

What's the best way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a timezone from its "Id":

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
```

[GetSystemTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) will give you the list of Ids.  Note: these are framework 3.5 methods.

Comment: I just figured that out and logged back on to answer my own question, but you beat me to it!  As you point out, the trick is to store it in the Profile as an Id and not DisplayName.  Thanks.